# Can I get the original MAC address after it has been changed?

Tags: linux, mac-address

I am using some linux machines that have had their MAC address changed. I would like to be able to read it back with a shell script.

Is the original MAC address stored anywhere except the sticker on the box?
How do I bring back the original hardware address?

Answer (score 6):

you can check you `dmesg` logs it will report the hardware MAC address as seen on boot.

on one of my boxes the output looks like:

```
gbeech@ny-man01:~$ dmesg | grep eth0
[    6.533181] eth0: Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5709 1000Base-T (C0) PCI Express found at mem d6000000, IRQ 36, node addr 00:21:9b:a0:b7:cc
```

what you are interested in is the `node addr 00:21:9b:a0:b7:cc` bit at the end

Comment: Guess what... I'm using a weird ARM machine with uBoot that sets mac to a value from settings and I have to duplicate the settings between machines, so... I ended up saving the mac address in a file and setting it up on each boot. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Might be on the physical card, or etched onto the motherboard.  I doubt you can access it from a script however.